# Property touch-action doesn't exist : none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using CSS code:

```
.ui-resizable{position:relative}.ui-resizable-handle{position:absolute;font-size:.1px;display:block;-ms-touch-action:none;touch-action:none}.ui-resizable-autohide
```

Getting error in WC3 validation:

> Property touch-action doesn't exist : none

Comment: u have to use  width and height i think

Comment: ui-resizable-handle{width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;font-size:.1px;display:block;-ms-touch-action:none;touch-action:none} where width height u can write what u want